# Automapper configure to only take source if source is not null?

Tags: automapper

Is there a way in Automapper configuration to only map a value in the source to the destination if the source is not null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Conditional Mapping](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Conditional-mapping):

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
  cfg.CreateMap<Foo,Bar>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.baz, opt => opt.Condition(src => (src.baz != null))); 
});
```